# Boolean properties in gradle.properties file is read as string

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle. I have a boolean property in gradle.properties file. When I tried to access it, the property is set as string. The string property always seemed to be evaluated as true when the string is not null and not empty.

My gradle.properties looks like this

```
enableGradleApp=false
```

and my settings.gradle looks like

```
if (enableGradleApp) {
println 'Enabled core'
}
```

The message 'Enabled Core' is always gets printed.

Need some help please

Comment: Works as designed, all properties read from a property file are strings.

Comment: I just (re)opened: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2632

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I just converted it to `boolean` like this:

```
if (enableGradleApp.toBoolean()) {
  ....
}
```